# SPA with .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, url-rewriting

I have created a single page application using .NET MVC at the core with AngularJS ( not really important as routing is in almost popular js frameworks now ).

I use the MVC component instead of a regular page to do some dynamic variable, app startup type configuration.

In order to stop default routing from occurring and keep my pages routed to the `Default.cshtml` page I use URL Rewrite in my web.config like:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!lib|api|assets|app/|common|main|app.min|signalr|templates).*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.cshtml" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

My angular app then uses `html5Mode` routing which uses native urls instead of hashbang hack.  This works fine, but it feel really nasty.  I modeled this from http://tarkus.me/post/32121691785/angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-4.

My question is: Is there a better/more clean way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the same setup (MVC + JS framework) and handle the redirection of web requests via route configuration.

AppStart in the global.asax calls a route config method to build all the application routes.

In there I just modify the existing default route to always go to the controller/action of my choosing (typically Home/Index) this way any request coming to the site get returned the same response.

**Update** code example:

This way you're not defining any parts in the url, but hard-code the defaults to always go to the controller/action you want

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: That is quite a bit nicer, do you also have Home and Index in a c# controller like comes out of the box?  I assume so..

Comment: When you create a new MVC project in Visual Studio it typically creates it. That being said, if you select "Empty" then I don't believe it does.